# Can not delete an animation action

Tags: animation, data-blocks

Like to preface this by saying i have searched the whole internet to no avail, found several people with this problem (usually several years ago) but never found an answer that helped.

For some reason there is a junk action that can not be deleted.

[image]

As you can see, all of my actions are fine and dandy except for Cube.040.action.
When I export as FBX into unity, it can often nearly crash Unity because there are all of these junk animations called [Object Name]|Cube.040Action.[image]

This action is not visible in the NLA editor, cannot be cleared in the outliner, cannot be deleted in Data-Blocks and cannot be cleared by python unless I'm missing something.

What leads me to believe it is some kind of bug is occasionally it will appear in the NLA editor, but is not deletable as the expand button does nothing when clicked.

Any help would be appreciated and im willing to upload the blend file if that would be helpful.

Comment: Any blend file would be helpful usually. I would advise you do so, as we can spot and troubleshoot the problem with accuracy.

Comment: Here is the blend - http://www.mediafire.com/file/dh5p8a0qhf1r2pp/external_player.blend

Answer (score 8):

In the outliner, switch the type of information to display to *Blender File*. Extend *Current File > actions*. There you have your Cube-Action – right click it and select *delete*. See screenshot below.

[image: delete action]

Comment: Blender is broken, a couple of days ago I had the same question as OP and solved it with your way, but now it does not work anymore, there is no delete option anymore!

Answer (score 0):

In blenders NLA Editor there's this option Edit > Remove Empty Animation Data. Additionally, try Object > Make Local > All and File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend. Maybe this mysterious cube is visible and deleteable then. Does that help?

Comment: The Remove Empty Animation Data command did get rid of some extra blank nla strips that were annoying me, but the Cube.040Action itself still persists and appears to be associated with many objects. I delete Cube.040 and that changed nothing, I dont think it was even associated with the action. Appreciate it though.

Comment: In this case, try to import your objects into a completely new blend file. If this doesn't help, I'm at a loss, too.   :)