# How to delete an action?

Tags: animation

I try to delete Action.005 permanently.

[image]

But I don't know how. If I click on the `X`

[image]

then it is still in the list.

[image]

I already researched without success, I even managed to loose all my animations by attempting to apply a fix, so I want to be cautious now... How can I do this?

Comment: I finally found the solution in this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/88385/19208

Comment: Now It does not even work after applying the solution from the link above... seems like a bug

Comment: Did you try pressing Shift+X instead of X? Then reloading the file.

Comment: Can you provide an example .blend file? Using the example in the link above, I was able to delete an action.

Comment: i had similar problem once, i remember i had to delete actions in NLA editor

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Probably best way is change **Outliner** into **Blender File** mode, right click on action and click delete.

[image: Action Delete]

Comment: Still very useful in 2021! :) They could've made that a little bit easier...

Comment: The button for selecting the mode seems to not be available anymore in Blender 2.92.x

Comment: Still relevant in 2024, Blender 4.0.2
For beginners (like me) who aren't aware, the outline in the default layout is the list of objects in the top-right. You change the mode by opening the Display Mode drop-down (look at tooltips) and selecting Blender File.

Answer (score 7):

To remove an action you need to disable `Fake user` option with `F` button and then click `X` button. After that you will see no active action in action editor (That will have only one button to create new action `+ New`). Clicking on button that opens list of actions you will see action that you removed with `0` at the beginning of this name (like `0 MyUselessAction`). It means that has 0 references on it. Saving your scene and loading it again will remove that dangling reference from `.blend` file

Answer (score 3):

Shift-click on the X, save, and reload/re-open the file. The action should be gone. (This incidentally should work with practically any data block.)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. One is to go to the NLA Editor and remove the action by pressing the delete button on the selected action (you might need to click the drop down button on the parent animation). The second option is to go to the Hiercy(objects panel) and select your object with the animation, click the plus icon to the left of the animations sub menu and right click on the action you want to remove, then you can see a delete option, follow by clicking it and it should be removed. If you find your action only listed in the NLA Sheets menu, then you can only use the first option.

There is a similar question here:[Can not delete actions in action editor even with Shift + x](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36129/can-not-delete-actions-in-action-editor-even-with-shift-x)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Remove It Completely you could just use this code:

```
import bpy
name = "MyAction"

bpy.data.actions.remove(bpy.data.actions[name])
```

Just Paste It in The Text Editor, replace *MyAction* with The name of your action in the second line and Press ***Run Script*** or **Alt**+**P**.

Keep in mind You should not be able to undo after using this techinque, so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Select your action in the Action Editor, then unfold *Armature > Animation* and right in the *Animation* tab there will be your action. Now just <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> > *Delete*

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 2.8

1. In the **Actions Editor**, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse click</kbd>  on the 'x' button (next to the shield icon or even next to it), all the actions-data will be cleared from the file.
2. Go to *Outliner* menu (the one on the top right corner in animations tab) and click on the **display mode** button (left to the search bar), it will show a drop - down menu and click on *Blender File* option, now you can see actions. <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> on the specific action which you want to delete and press delete. It's permanently gone!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the "Nonlinear Animation" window and remove anything unnecessary, then save your file and reopen it with Blender.