# Lots of Junk Animation Sequences in my Blender File

Tags: animation

[image]

Hi, I’m working on my first video game and I’m having issues organizing and deleting some animation sequences. I designed all the characters and assets in one Blender file and I’m exporting everything into Unity. As a beginner, I’m sure I made some mistakes along the way when doing the animations. In my Dope Sheet/Action Editor, there are a lot of animation sequences that I didn’t intend to create, some of which are for stationary assets. I think this is because I had the “automatic keyframe” button pressed during my regular workflow, even when I was not animating, although I’m not sure this is the sole reason. I tried to delete some of these sequences but I have been unable to figure it out. I read somewhere that the NLA editor allows you to delete animations but have had no luck. Further, it seems that many if not all the sequences are linked to multiple meshes. As a result, my Blender file is a bit of a jumbled mess of animations.

When I export my assets and characters to FBX files and import to Unity, they all bring a bunch of unrelated animations with them. Aside from that, several of the actual animations I need are not exporting with the FBX. For my main character, I designed 19 animations but 5 of them do not import in Unity, yet many of the “junk” sequences, mostly associated with other assets, do import with that character.

Not sure how big of a problem this will be moving forward but I would like to figure out what I did wrong and how to fix it. Also, if there are any good tutorials on proper animation workflow in Blender, I would appreciate it. I’ve seen a few but they deal mostly with small scale projects (one mesh/character). I’ll gladly share my files via email. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
-Brian

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36129/can-not-delete-actions-in-action-editor-even-with-shift-x   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88188/can-not-delete-an-animation-action

Comment: Sometimes I find starting from an empty  file and appending to it from original a good way to clean the file.

Comment: @batFINGER thanks for your response. If I start from a new file, won't I have to redo all the animations? Because if I copy the armature, won't all the junk animations copy with it?